# what is %-4relative in logback.xml log pattern specification

Tags: spring, logback

What does %-4relative mean? I can't find a definition anywhere.

"%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} **%-4relative** [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n" />

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In logback `%relative` means print relative timestamp in milliseconds since the start of the aplication.

`%-4` is just alignment of the element.